# Using specific python version for apt-get in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, apt, python, python-2.7

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I have `python2.7.3-0Ubuntu3.5` package installed.
One of the libraries i am trying to install has dependency on (>=2.7.3.6).

I went ahead and installed `python 2.7.6` and even `python --version shows 2.7.6`
But when I run `apt-get install` to install the package it gives me error message:

```
Has dependency on (>=2.7.3.6) but python2.7.3-0Ubuntu3.5 is to be installed.
```

I am just wondering why is it still pointing to `python2.7.3-0Ubuntu3.5`.

Any help will be appreciated. I have gone through dozens of posts without no luck and have been stuck on this issue for long.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to delete the old version of python and then do the install of the new version.

Also always do `sudo apt-get update` before you install software.

Comment: I cannot delete the old python version, it will mess up the Ubuntu OS. Unity and other applications use python for their working. and yeah I am doing sudo apt-get update before I am installing software

Comment: Could you try to use this way of installing the latest version of python? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6630994/2932698

Comment: That is what I exactly did.. Hence python --version returns 2.7.6. But apt-get install since gives that 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.5 needs to be (or rather is) installed

Answer (score 0):

What you do outside the package system doesn't help dependencies inside it. Since you installed 2.7.6 from source, you'll have to install that library from source as well, if you want it to use the 2.7.6 version.

Or you could find a PPA that provides the required version of Python, or build a package of the correct version yourself.